org.apache.tomcat.jni.LibraryNotFoundError: Can't load library tcnative-2.dll spring-boot 3
:: Spring Boot ::               (v3.2.10)
2024-10-17T11:05:17.697+01:00  INFO 27168 --- [           main] m.i.conformite.ConformiteApplication     : Startstrong texting ConformiteApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 27168 (C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite\target\classes started by ayoub in C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite)
2024-10-17T11:05:17.699+01:00  INFO 27168 --- [           main] m.i.conformite.ConformiteApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-10-17T11:05:18.297+01:00  INFO 27168 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-10-17T11:05:18.401+01:00  INFO 27168 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 95 ms. Found 15 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-10-17T11:05:18.710+01:00  WARN 27168 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'springDataAccessConfig' of type [ma.incepture.conformite.config.SpringDataAccessConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [exceptionTranslation] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.
2024-10-17T11:05:18.828+01:00 DEBUG 27168 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The Apache Tomcat Native library could not be found using names [tcnative-2, libtcnative-2, tcnative-1, libtcnative-1] on the java.library.path [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\test;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\bureau\Android\apktool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\7.0.0\bin..\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\bin;;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop;;.]. The errors reported were [Can't load library: C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite\bin\tcnative-2.dll, Can't load library: C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite\bin\libtcnative-2.dll, Can't load library: C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite\bin\tcnative-1.dll, Can't load library: C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite\bin\libtcnative-1.dll, no tcnative-2 in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\test;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\bureau\Android\apktool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\7.0.0\bin..\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\bin;;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop;;., no libtcnative-2 in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\test;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\bureau\Android\apktool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\7.0.0\bin..\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\bin;;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop;;., no tcnative-1 in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\test;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\bureau\Android\apktool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\7.0.0\bin..\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\bin;;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop;;., no libtcnative-1 in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\test;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\bureau\Android\apktool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\7.0.0\bin..\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\bin;;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop;;.]
org.apache.tomcat.jni.LibraryNotFoundError: Can't load library: C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite\bin\tcnative-2.dll, Can't load library: C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite\bin\libtcnative-2.dll, Can't load library: C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite\bin\tcnative-1.dll, Can't load library: C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\java 17\conformite\bin\libtcnative-1.dll, no tcnative-2 in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\test;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\bureau\Android\apktool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\7.0.0\bin..\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\bin;;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop;;., no libtcnative-2 in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\test;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\bureau\Android\apktool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\7.0.0\bin..\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\bin;;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop;;., no tcnative-1 in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\test;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\bureau\Android\apktool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\7.0.0\bin..\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\bin;;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop;;., no libtcnative-1 in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/ayoub/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_23.0.0.v20240919-1706/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15.1\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\test;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop\bureau\Android\apktool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\7.0.0\bin..\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\ayoub\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.9-bin\apache-maven-3.9.9\bin\bin;;C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop;;.
at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.(Library.java:91) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:113) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getDefaultServerLifecycleListeners(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:189) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:136) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at ma.incepture.conformite.ConformiteApplication.tomcatFactory(ConformiteApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
at ma.incepture.conformite.ConformiteApplication$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$tomcatFactory$0() ~[classes/:na]
at ma.incepture.conformite.ConformiteApplication$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:348) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at ma.incepture.conformite.ConformiteApplication$$SpringCGLIB$$0.tomcatFactory() ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:223) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:186) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619) ~[spring-context-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.2.10.jar:3.2.10]
at ma.incepture.conformite.ConformiteApplication.main(ConformiteApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
